# C programming: How could you compare two types without ==

Tags: c, comparison, bit-manipulation

I was wondering how the C compiler would handle the comparison operator '=='

I wish to create a function (in C) that compares two things without using the ==. I think it can be done some how by using bitwise operators ( &, |, ^, >>) however I can't seem to think of how to do it.

Anyone have ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: depends on the type of THING's your tring to compare, boolean, ints, string, objects?

Comment: Any particular kind of "thing"?

Comment: hint: think about what each of those operators do

Comment: Not homework! Call it curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple way to check if two ints are equal without using `==`:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 3;

if(x < y || y < x)
    printf("Not equal");
else
    printf("Equal");
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, another way I did it was to convert the number into binary and use a digital comparator method here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator

Comment: The trick with less-than operator is used e.g. by STL map, which is actually a tree map. It is enough to have a strict weak ordering on the keys (similar to the behavior of < for numbers) to find the key. operator==() is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

For integral types, `if (!(a - b))` will work.

You might run into some funny problems with other types.

Maybe `if (!(a ^ b))`?

Comment: `a-b` may be an undefined behavior

Comment: `a - b` might be undefined behavior if `b` is an `int` of value `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `==`:

```
int is_a_equal_to_b(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b || a < b) return 0; /* Not equal. */
    return 1;                     /* Equal.     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you invert every bit of one of the values and then "&" the two values together. If the result is zero, then they should be equal.

```
int x=5;
int y=5;
int z=(~x)&y;

if(!(y>0||y<0)){
   //Values are equal. 
}
```

Why don't you want to use the "==" operator?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wondering how the compiler does it, it translates `==` into machine code that contains a `cmp` instruction. This instruction compares two operands, and stores the result of the comparison. The result can be checked to see if the operands were equal, not equal, less than, greater than, etc.

In the case of using `==` in an `if` statement, it would probably generate something like this:

```
cmp op1, op2
jne else_address
```

which basically means 'Compare the two values. If they are not equal, skip to the else block.'

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good, but if you want only bitwise operators, do something like:

```
int is_equal(int a,int b) {
 int bit=1;
 while(bit) {
  if ((a&bit)^(b&bit)) return 0;
  bit<<=1;
 }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `if(a ^ b) return 0; else return 1;` instead of doing that to each bit one at a time.